# Getting the first value in an array from child Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm just starting with Svelte but I have a feeling this more of a JS issue i'm running in to.

A child component is fetching and exporting back  a JSON object from a url given as a property in the parent.
After receiving the object I'm looking for a specific index (0) and then logging one of the values.

However in this moment I'm getting the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

When removing the index I get a perfect array in my console but for some reason I cannot display an individual value.

Also tried with an imported function but the result is exactly the same.
You can see this last try here (based on an existing fetch.js function):

```js
import fetchStore from './fetch.js'
const [data, loading, error, get] = fetchStore(url)
$: console.log($data.results[0].name);
```

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export default function (url) {
    const loading = writable(false)
    const error = writable(false)
    const data = writable({})
    
    async function get() {
        loading.set(true)
        error.set(false)
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url)
            data.set(await response.json())
        } catch(e) {
            error.set(e)
        }
        loading.set(false)
    }
    
    get()
    
    return [ data, loading, error, get]
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/404e765f91d94aa190caf929bd7532e3?version=3.50.1)

Why can't I access an index of this array that was imported from a child?

Comment: Please do not just link off-site, questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the store content is loaded asynchronously, but initialized to an empty object:

```js
const data = writable({})
```

It reads `results` (undefined) and than accesses index 0.

Either check for `results` first or initialize the store differently. E.g.

```js
$: if ($data.results) console.log($data.results[0].name);
```